# How to switch between home screens via code in Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to change between screens via code? We swipe right/left to switch between multiple screen we have. Is it possible to emulate that via code? Should we emulate swipe programmatically to achieve this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Is this your launcher or another launcher installed on the device?

Comment: I have only default launcher.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot attack other applications by injecting key or touch events in them, unless those are your own apps, and even then only through creating special unit test suite projects.

Second, you assume that the "home screen" has a concept of "multiple screens". Not all do.